# Observer was not registered. ListView Adapter crashing sometime

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a service that is downloading some photos album data and there is a Activity. The serveice has a reference of Activity and calls method of the activity notifying the UI to show latest list data that is in queue. The service calls an activity-method that has as handler to update UI e.g

```
public void askForChecheList ( ) {
    galleryHandler.sendEmptyMessage ( 5 ) ;
}
```

Where handler is like

```
private Handler galleryHandler = new Handler() {
    @ Override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        // ...
        if ( msg.what == 5 ) {
            showUpdatedList ( ) ;
        }
    }
};
```

I am updating listView item with following code:

```
private synchronized void showUpdatedList ( ) {

    try {

        checkForPhotoService ( ) ;
        if ( mPhotoSyncService != null ) {
            this.mAllAlbumsData = mPhotoSyncService.getSyncAlbumsList ( ) ;
        }
        if ( mAlbumQueuedListAdapter == null ) {
            mAlbumQueuedListAdapter = new AlbumQueueListAdapter ( mContext , mAllAlbumsData ) ;
            mQueuedListView.setAdapter ( mAlbumQueuedListAdapter ) ;
        } else {
            mAlbumQueuedListAdapter.setData ( mAllAlbumsData ) ;
            mAlbumQueuedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ( );
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
    }
}
```

But Don't know sometime it crash the application with this log. I have a very good experience of using listView , Adapter but I am getting this error first time. Did anyone experience that do?

```
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@413afb00 was not registered.
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedList(StatusActivity.java:326)
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.getCachedList(StatusActivity.java:228)
01-19 23:21:01.139: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.PhotoSyncService.downloadAlbums(PhotoSyncService.java:540)
01-19 23:21:01.144: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.PhotoSyncService.onHandleIntent(PhotoSyncService.java:111)
01-19 23:21:01.144: W/System.err(13013): at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
01-19 23:21:01.144: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 23:21:01.144: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-19 23:21:01.144: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@413afb00 was not registered.
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedList(StatusActivity.java:326)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.getCachedList(StatusActivity.java:228)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedValues(StatusActivity.java:275)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.access$4(StatusActivity.java:259)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity$2.handleMessage(StatusActivity.java:93)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@413afb00 was not registered.
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedList(StatusActivity.java:326)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.getCachedList(StatusActivity.java:228)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedValues(StatusActivity.java:275)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.access$4(StatusActivity.java:259)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity$2.handleMessage(StatusActivity.java:93)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-19 23:21:01.174: W/System.err(13013): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 23:21:02.589: W/System.err(13013): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@413afb00 was not registered.
01-19 23:21:02.609: W/System.err(13013): at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
01-19 23:21:02.609: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
01-19 23:21:02.609: W/System.err(13013): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
01-19 23:21:02.609: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.showUpdatedList(StatusActivity.java:326)
01-19 23:21:02.619: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity.getCachedList(StatusActivity.java:228)
01-19 23:21:02.619: W/System.err(13013): at au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase.activities.StatusActivity$2.handleMessage(StatusActivity.java:97)
01-19 23:21:02.619: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-19 23:21:02.629: W/System.err(13013): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution for your handler problem, but I would recommend using the **observer-pattern** in order to avoid the problems you are having, I found this **[site](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/)** which should explain the logic how to do this properly.